# SQL query sum column till a row condition met and continue sum column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Data:

[image]

SQL Server 2012 - I need to "scan" through a table as shown above and sum up the duration column until the row having "BREAK" in Paycode column.

Then continue to sum up duration column after the "BREAK" row

i.e. i want to get results of

```
Sum of Duration
---------------
6.08
3.33
```

I tried this statement, but it's not returning the above desired result:

```
SELECT duration, paycode, visitstart
INTO #client
FROM VISITS
WHERE visitstart > '2020-01-20'
  AND visitstart < '2020-01-21'
  AND paycode <> 'BREAK'
ORDER BY VISITSTART, CLIENT_ID

SELECT SUM(duration) AS total_duration, visitstart, paycode
FROM #client
GROUP BY visitstart, paycode

DROP TABLE #client
```

Please kindly advise

Comment: provide your expected output in tabular format

Comment: It would also help if you set up a db/sql fiddle -- or at least put data in your question as text or DDL statements.  Images are not useful.

Comment: my apologies just realised using SQL server 2008 (SP3-GDR) <br/> select sum(duration) as total_duration
from
(
select visits.*,
 row_number() over (order by visitstart) as seqnum,
 row_number() over (partition by case when paycode = 'BREAK'
 then 1 else 0 end order by visitstart) as seqnumt
 from visits 
 ) visits
where paycode <> 'BREAK'
and EMP_ID = 'S0000000182'
and visitstart > '2020-01-20' 
and visitstart < '2020-01-21'
group by seqnum, seqnumt <br/>

Comment: @SteveC . . . Why are you using an unsupported version of a commercial product?

Comment: Steve C, I have specially write query for Sql server 2008...Do you try my query?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below one - it's a `gap & island` problem

```
select sum(duration) as total_duration
from
(
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by visitstart) as seqnum,
       row_number() over (partition by case when paycode='Break' then 1 else 0 end order by visitstart) as seqnumt
from yourtablename t
)A 
where paycode<>'Break'
group by (seqnum-seqnumt)
```

Comment: Can you explain more about `case when paycode='Break' then 1 else 0`? It take me more time to figure out. I think it would confusing many SQL beginners like me.

Comment: @劉鎮瑲, It is for creating a group based on your paycode.

Comment: Is it means group by Break  else group every paycode together?

Comment: @劉鎮瑲, yes that's it

Comment: my apologies just realised using SQL server 2008 (SP3-GDR) <br/> select sum(duration) as total_duration
from
(
select visits.*,
 row_number() over (order by visitstart) as seqnum,
 row_number() over (partition by case when paycode = 'BREAK'
 then 1 else 0 end order by visitstart) as seqnumt
 from visits 
 ) visits
where paycode <> 'BREAK'
and EMP_ID = 'S0000000182'
and visitstart > '2020-01-20' 
and visitstart < '2020-01-21'
group by seqnum, seqnumt <br/>

Comment: it just return the results of duration column as below please advise <br/> total_duration 0.5000 1.0000 0.2500 0.1667 1.0000 0.5000 0.5000 0.1667 2.0000 0.5000 1.5000 0.3333 1.0000

Answer (score 1):

You can assign groups by summing the number of times that "BREAK" appears.  Then you can aggregate.  I am not quite sure how the final durations are defined -- in particular whether the "BREAK" row is included.  Assuming that it is:

```
select min(visitstart), max(visitstart),
       sum(duration)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when paycode = 'BREAK' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by visitstart) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where paycode <> 'BREAK'
group by grp
```

Comment: my apologies just realised using SQL server 2008 (SP3-GDR)

SELECT min(visitstart), max(visitstart), sum(duration)
from
    (select *, 
    sum(case when paycode = 'BREAK' then 1 else 0 end) 
    over (order by visitstart)
 from visits
 )
visits
where paycode <> 'BREAK'
group by visitstart

it's saying incorrect syntax near 'order' at line 5
it's highlighting bottom third line visits
 (no column was specified for column 57 of 'visits')

Comment: @SteveC . . . SQL Server 2008 is unsupported.  You should be using supported software.

Comment: Hi thanks for this your query (i replaced order by with partition by) seems produced sum duration results of all records but how to produce sum duration of top nine records (excluding BREAK record) and subsequent four records thereafter BREAK record ?

Comment: @SteveC . . . "I need to "scan" through a table as shown above and sum up the duration column until the row having "BREAK" in Paycode column."  I think this does what htis question asks.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.  And you should accept one of the answers to thisone.

Comment: My original question continued as "Then continue to sum up duration column after the "BREAK" row

i.e. i want to get results of

Sum of Duration
---------------
6.08
3.33

Answer (score 0):

So,Steve C, I have tried to help you...
I have made several cte

1. cte (cteBreak) -  you are just select only breaks.
2. cte (breaks_chains) - numbering each break (because can't use row_numbing)
3. breaks_chains- get breaks intervals by pair (eg
   time first break - time second break,
   time second break-time third break)

Note: if it is last interval  then column end_break is replacing by getdate(), just to close interval

4. and at last we combine our table with breaks_chains
   Instead of Table type yours Table name

   ```
   --just get rows with BREAK paycode
    with cteBreak as
     (
       select * from Table where paycode='BREAK'
     ),

    --numbering breaks (=row_numbering() in later version sql server)
    breaks_chains as
    (
     select cte1.visitstart visit_st,count(cte2.visitstart)+1 Num from cteBreak cte1
     left join cteBreak cte2
     on cte1.visitstart>cte2.visitstart
     group by cte1.visitstart
    ),

    --get pairs as "start_break - end_break"
    break_interval as
    (
     select t1.visit_st begin_break, COALESCE(t2.visit_st,getdate()) as end_break,t1.Num from 
     breaks_chains t1
     left join breaks_chains t2
     on t2.Num-t1.Num=1
    )


    select sum(duration) from
    (
    select duration,paycode,
     case
        when 
           (Table.visitstart>break_interval.begin_break
            and Table.visitstart<break_interval.end_break)
        then break_interval.end_break    

        when (Table.visitstart<break_interval.begin_break and Num=1)
        then  break_interval.begin_break
    end NumGroup
    from Table
    left join break_interval
    on 
      (Table.visitstart>break_interval.begin_break  
      and Table.visitstart<break_interval.end_break)
    or 
      (Table.visitstart<break_interval.begin_break and Num=1) --for first sequence (before first break)
    )t
    where paycode<>'BREAK'
    group by NumGroup
   ```

P.S. If you have questions, write it in comments please)

Comment: Tell me, do you run it?